# Google Sheets Custom Function Timing Out

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

So I have been having erratically getting an error: "Internal Error Executing the Custom Function" when running my custom function on a decently sized range of cells.

Google specifies "A custom function call must return within 30 seconds. If it does not, the cell will display an error: Internal error executing the custom function."

My custom function is this:

```
function ConcatLoop(rangeString, concatString, isPrefix, isOneColumn) {
  //var rangeString = "A1:A10,B1:B10,C1:C10";
  //var concatString = "1x ";
  //var isPrefix = "true";
  //var isOneColumn = "true";  

  var rangeStringArray = rangeString.split(',');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rangeValues=[];

  //GRABBING THE VALUES FROM EACH RANGE
  for(i=0;i<rangeStringArray.length;i++)
  {
    var range = sheet.getRange(rangeStringArray[i]);
    rangeValues.push(range.getValues());
  }

  if(isOneColumn){var newRangeValues = [[]]};

  //REMOVES EMPTY STRINGS AND ARRAYS OR CONCATENATES THE STRINGS
  for (i = 0; i < rangeValues.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < rangeValues[i].length; j++){
      if (rangeValues[i][j] == "") 
      {         
        rangeValues[i].splice(j, 1);
        j--;
      }
      else if(isPrefix == "true")
      {
        rangeValues[i][j] = concatString + rangeValues[i][j];
        if(isOneColumn){newRangeValues[0].push(rangeValues[i][j])};
      }
      else
      {
        rangeValues[i][j] = rangeValues[i][j] + concatString;
        if(isOneColumn){newRangeValues[0].push(rangeValues[i][j])};
      }
    }
    if (rangeValues[i] ==""){
      rangeValues.splice(i,1);
      i--;
    }
  }

  //LOG WHILE TESTING
  //if(isOneColumn){Logger.log(JSON.stringify(newRangeValues))}
  //else{Logger.log("range values after concat: " + rangeValues)}

  //RETURN WHILE RUNNING
  if(isOneColumn){return newRangeValues}
  else{return rangeValues};
}
```

When I have 1000 values plugged into the function, it takes quite a while to pull all the values. It runs fine when I test it in GOogle Scripts, because there isn't a time constraint there.

If there is anything I can do to work around this or make this more efficient, could someone let me know? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can your range passed be A1:C10 or however far over you are going?  The time consumption is in the getValues() calls.  [Googles Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices)  suggest making 1 call if possible

Comment: It is going through multiple sheets. I need specific columns too, like Sheet1!A1:A100 and Sheet2!E1:E:100, etc. I am making probably 150 calls at this point. So I should just through the entire sheet in as 1 range? That would condense it down to 27 calls. There are 27 sheets.

Comment: If you have 27 Sheets how are you making more than one call per sheet? Can you share an example of how you call this function from the spreadsheet with an example argument

Comment: I split a string of ranges on commas, creating an array of ranges. So I would pass in something like: "Sheet1!A1:A100,Sheet1!B1:B100,Sheet2!A1:A100,Sheet2!B1:B100"

Then I throw it in a for loop and continuously call getValues()

Comment: You can instead pass Sheet1!A1:B100,Sheet2A1:B100 and so one. This will reduce the number of calls to getValues() and improve your execution speed. I believe that is what you are planning to do anyway, based on your previous comment. If that doesn't work you can just call the function from script editor, it has a 5min execution time limit. Hope that helps, all the best

Comment: You COULD call the ranges to force the function to run when one of the ranges changes but internally read all of each sheet, then use code to grab the parts you need.  At least then you are only doing 27 getValues(). AND getting the update to happen.

Comment: I could definitely tell that the Script Editor didn't have much of a time limitation! I should have given a better example. I am doing something similar to "Sheet1!A1:A100,Sheet1!Y1:Y100". I have 27 sheets and 7 columns that are spread out across each sheet. I was thinking about passing in nearly the entire sheet to reduce the amount of getValues calls.

Comment: Looks like @Karl_S had a very similar idea! I would be exchanging memory for efficiency in processing. Might this work well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the incredible individuals who commented, I did find an answer earlier, so I'm going to post it for anyone who might need it.

Google sets a limitation of 30 seconds for the execution time of any custom function on a spreadsheet. Anything above that will give you an internal error. Although there is a limitation of 5 minutes for the execution time in the Script Editor, there is probably an issue if your script takes over 30 seconds to execute. In my case, I had too many separate ranges I needed to pull data out of. So I was calling "getValues(range)" quite a few times within a for-loop.

The solution was to pull each entire sheet in the spreadsheet as one range. So rather than having 7 ranges for each of my 27 sheets, I had 1 range for each of my 27 sheets. This caused me to have an excess amount of unnecessary information in memory, but also caused the execution time to go from around 45 seconds to 10 seconds. Solved my problem entirely.

Thank you!